# looking for a library for mml filetype

Tags: r

I am wondering if the is an R library that can read the .mml filetype? I have been trying to find a way to read this filetype into an R dataframe but cannot find anything. I'm guessing the filetype is a json style file from an Adobe program.

I've tried this:

```
df1 <- rjson::fromJSON(file='file.mml')
```

But get this:

```
Error in fromJSON(file = origFile) : 
    not all data was parsed (0 chars were parsed out of a total of 3771444 chars)
```

I am able to open the file in Excel but am just curious if anyone knows of an R library.